# Running multiple Django apps under same domain with Gunicorn & Nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have a static website that works `domain.com` and a Django project that works `domain.com/djangoproject1`, now I'm trying to add another Django project as `domain.com/djangoproject2`, this is my `sites-avaliable`

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

#upstream djangoapp1 { # This did not work
#    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
#}

#upstream djangoapp2 { # This did not work
#    server 127.0.0.1:7000 fail_timeout=0;
#}


server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name ...;
  ssl_certificate ...
  ssl_certificate_key ...;

  root /var/www/portfolio; #Serves static portfolio and works
  index index.html; #Serves static portfolio and works

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  
  location /djangoapp1static/ { #Works for app 1 and matches settings
      alias /home/djangoapp1...
  }

  location /djangoapp2static/ {
      alias /home/djangoapp2...
  }

  location /djangoapp1{
    alias /home/djangoapp1/src/;
    include proxy_params;

    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock; #WORKS
    #proxy_pass http://djangoapp1; #Does not work even without the second app
    #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000; #Does not work even without the second app
    

  }

  location /djangoapp2{
    alias /home/djangoapp2/src/;
    include proxy_params;


    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/djangoapp2.sock; #This works for djangoapp1 but not for this one


    #proxy_pass http://djangoapp2; #Tried did not work
    #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000; #Tried did not work

  }


}
```

Currently the `djangoapp1` works normally while the `djangoapp2` works only when I manually run it with `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:7000 config.wsgi` so it must have something to do with `gunicorn` `djangoapp2.sock` exists, the `sites-avaliable` is linked to `sites-enabled` so not a problem.

when I `sudo systemctl status djangoapp2` I get

```
    × djangoapp2.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/djangoapp2.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-12-23 08:04:16 UTC; 41min ago
   Duration: 462ms
TriggeredBy: × djangoapp2.socket
   Main PID: 47712 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 455ms
```

`.service` files are changed and named correspondingly to the apps

according to https://www.ryancheley.com/2021/03/07/setting-up-multiple-django-sites-on-a-digital-ocean-server/ what I'm trying to do should be possible

Is anyone hosting mutiple Django apps like I'm trying to do? I do not want `djangoapp1.domain.com` and `djangoapp2.domain.com`, I want them to be `/djangoapp1` and `/djangoapp2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed two instances of gunicorn, each in its own venv instead of using the global `usr/bin/gunicorn`. Re-created `.service` and `.socket` files, `start` -> `enable` -> reload everything, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best at doing this is by creating individual services for the apps and setting them up to run on startup.
You can follow the guide [here](https://caterinadmitrieva.medium.com/serving-multiple-django-apps-on-second-level-domains-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-a4a14804174c) , which explains the details pretty well.

Assuming you have configured your django/flask app to manage the routes on /djangoapp1 and /djangoapp2.

Hope this helps.